# Notify Lambda on CloudFront Distribution Creation End

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

At the moment, we are calling `cloudfront.listDistributions()` every minute to identify a change in the status of the distribution we are deploying. This cause Lambda to timeout because CloudFront never deploys faster than 30 minutes (where Lambda timeouts after 15 min).

I would like to **notify a Lambda function after a CloudFront Distribution is successfully created**. This would allow us to execute the post-creation actions while saving valuable Lambda exec time.

Creating a Rule on CloudWatch does not offer the option to chose CloudFront. Nevertheless, it seems to accept creating a *Custom Event Pattern* with the source `aws.cloudformation`.

[image]

Considering options:

- Trigger a lambda every 5 minutes to list distributions and compare states with previous states stored in DynamoDB.

Anybody with an idea to overcome this lack of feature from AWS?

Comment: FYI - also on Reddit : https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/by8n7x/notify_lambda_on_cloudfront_distribution_creation/

Comment: Hey Sébastien. What did you end up doing (if anything)?

Comment: @Theson I've ended up doing exactly what I said I would do: trigger lambda every N minutes to list CF distributions and compare actual state to a DB stored state.... Not optimal, but there seems to be no option to be notified of an event when a CF distribution changes its status... If anyone finds a way, or if the AWS stack evolves, I'm happy to review my comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want and have time, there's a trickier and a bit more complex solution for doing that leveraging CloudTrail.

**Disclaimer**

**CloudTrail is not a real-time log system, but ensure that all API calls will be reported on the console within 15 minutes (as stated here under the [CloudTrail FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/faqs/)). Due to this, what's following makes sense only for long-running tasks like creating a CloudFront distribution, taking up an Aurora DB ans so on.**

- You can create a CloudWatch event based rule (let's call it *CW-r1*)
  on specific pattern like *CreateDistribution* or
  *UpdateDistribution*.
- CW-r1 triggers a Lambda (*LM-1*) which enables another CloudWatch
  event base rule (CW-r2).
- CW-r2 on a scheduled base, triggers a Lambda (LM-2) which via API
  request the state of specific distribution. Once distribution is
  "Deployed", LM-2 can send a notification via SNS for example (you can
  send EMAIL, SMS, Push Notification whatever is supported on SNS).
- Once everything is finished, LM-2 can disable the CW-r2 rule in order
  to stop processing information.

In this way you can have an automatic notification system based on which API call you desire.